# Using py.test with compiled library code

Tags: python, build, pytest

I have a python library with the following repository structure:

```
repobase
 |- mylibrary
 |  |- __init__.py
 |- tests
    |- test_mylibrary.py
```

Up to now, running the tests could simply be done by calling `py.test` in the repobase directory. The `import mylibrary` in *test_mylibrary.py* then used the local code in *repobase/mylibrary*.

Now, I've extended the library to use compiled code. Therefore the source code at *repobase/mylibrary* is not functional on its own. I have to do a `setup.py build`. This creates *repobase/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mylibrary*.

**Is there a reasonable way to make py.test use this directory for importing mylibrary? Given these constraints:**

1. I do not want to include any `sys.path` / import magic in *test_mylibrary.py* because this may break tests in other envrionments.
2. I don't want to give up the possibility to run `py.test` from *repobase*. Therefore modifying the PYTHONPATH does not help because `.` will still be first in `sys.path`. And thus *repobase/mylibrary* would be favored over *repobase/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mylibrary*.

**If not, what's the standard way for testing python libraries, that need building?**

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "...I've extended the library to use compiled code...", i.e. does the compiled version provide the same interface as the Python version, or does the Python version `import` the compiled version? If the former, then you're effectively testing two different things, so perhaps they should have different names, even if the test suite is identical, q.v. Python's `pickle` vs `cPickle`. If the latter, then they should definitely have different names. A common Python idiom is for the compiled part to be prepended with an underscore, q.v. Python's `socket` vs `_socket`.

Comment: (continued) Either way, having two different module implementations sharing the same name is asking for trouble. Even if your solution works for all possible runtime cases today, you can't anticipate all possible future runtime cases, and you may end up importing or testing the wrong version without realizing it.

Comment: @Aya I've just one implementation. The compiled code *replaces* some formerly python code. As I have written "Therefore the source code at repobase/mylibrary is not functional on its own.". I need the compiled code to be able to run the tests.

Comment: So if the compiled code is supposed to replace the Python code, then can you not just eliminate the Python code from the repository? If the answer is "no" because it only replaces "some" of its functionality then it's not a true replacement, but rather an extension.

Comment: The python code is eliminated. Say, i have a function `do_something(args)` which was implemented in python. Now the python implementation was replaced by an internal call to some compiled c code. The API of `do_something` did not change and I still want to perfrom the same tests. Before the tests just run the raw code from `repobase/mylibrary`. After the change, this is not possible because the raw python code is not functional on its own anymore. Instead I have to `setup.py build` first and then use the code from the `build` subdirectory. The question is how to make py.test use that code.

Comment: So if the Python code is redundant, then simply remove `mylibrary/__init__.py` from the codebase, and put `repobase/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7` in your `PYTHONPATH`. Then point #2 in your question becomes a non-issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. For one, I cannot remove `mylibrary/__init__.py` because it contains functions other than `do_something` as well. Additionally it's my understanding that `mylibrary/__init__.py` should be in the repository where as `build/*` should not. The former is the *source code*, the latter the *executable code* which I need to run my tests on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115647/discussion-between-aya-and-tim-hoffmann).

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem is simply that py.test is not copying the built shared object to the root of your repository.

I just tried running the UT straight from the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ExtensionTutorial) on testing C extensions using py.test as follows:

```
python setup.py build
py.test test/examp_unittest.py
```

This failed with `AssertionError: No module named examp`.

However, when I follow the wiki to the letter (and run `python setup.py test` instead), I note that it copies the `.so` to the root directory (note the last line before it starts running the test):

```
running test
running egg_info
writing examp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to examp.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to examp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'examp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'examp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/examp.so ->
runTest (test.examp_unittest.DeviceTest) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Having run that on my system, I can now run py.test quite happily on the same code base - as shown below.

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /tmp/sotest, inifile: 
collected 1 items 

test/examp_unittest.py .

=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

The solution is therefore to copy your shared object to the root of your repository.

To make sure I have run the whole thing from scratch, just building the extension, copying the shared object and then running py.test.  This all works as expected.

Comment: I cannot really say, because I haven't had time yet to try it out (homefully tomorrow). I conclude from your example, that I have to run `python setup.py test`. But that will run standard unittests first (which is obsolete, because it will not discover and/or correctly treat all of my tests). It just costs extra time. Maybe then I should integrate pytest with setuptools (https://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner).

Comment: Still it feels somewhat wrong to have to run all tests every time. I often want to change some code, then build (because I have to for the compiled stuff) and then run a single test, e.g. `py.test tests/test_mylibrary.py::test_do_something`. Maybe I have to adapt `python setup.py build` or make a custom `python setup.py build_test` that just copies the required `.so` files. I'm really wondering why I cannot find anything in that direction because I would assume that it's a standard problem you encounter as soon as you use py.test and compiled code.

Comment: @TimHoffmann You dont need to run all your tests every time.  Simply run the build and copy the file yourself.  You could put that inside a bash script if you dislike typing as much as I do...

Comment: @TimHoffmann One further thought...  If you also have problems with your shared object clashing with the package name, just use an internl name instead.   For example, many projects use `_mylibrary` as the C extension for `mylibrary`.

Answer (score 3):

From the discussion in chat, it sounds as if the C implementation only provides a subset of the functionality of the Python implementation.

A common solution is to split the module such that the parts which require optimized implementations exist in a separate module.

Consider a more concrete example of a library which needs convert between different image formats.

Let's assume your layout looks like this...

```
repobase
 |- image
 |  |- __init__.py
 |  |- pyJPEG.py
 |- build
 |  |- lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
 |     |- cJPEG.so
 |- tests
    |- test_image.py
```

...your `PYTHONPATH` includes `/path/to/repobase:/path/to/repobase/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7`, your `cJPEG.so` exports symbols `jpeg_decompress` and `jpeg_compress`, and your files look like this...

**image/__init__.py**

```
# Load the C implementation if we have it, otherwise fall back to
# a pure Python implementation
try:
    from cJPEG import jpeg_decompress, jpeg_compress
except ImportError:
    from pyJPEG import jpeg_decompress, jpeg_compress

def load_image(filename):
    data = open(filename, 'rb').read()
    if filename.endswidth('.jpg'):
        return jpeg_decompress(data)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError

def save_image(data, filename, filetype='JPEG'):
    if filetype == 'JPEG':
        data = jpeg_compress(data)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError
    open(filename, 'wb').write(data)
```

**image/pyJPEG.py**

```
def jpeg_decompress(data):
    # A pure Python implementation of a JPEG decoder

def jpeg_compress(data):
    # A pure Python implementation of a JPEG encoder
```

With this sort of layout, the test suite need not care whether the library is built or not - you can use the same suite in both cases, and the presence (or absence) of `cJPEG.so` will determine which version is tested.